# How to have a Loading Spinner Animation on top of a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a spinner animation on `button` click. This Works fine from a page when there is no Bootstrap Modal Open. But when a Bootstrap Modal is Open, the Spinner hides behind the Bootstrap Modal

I have tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a9x7edq1/13/)

Expecting the Spinner to be above the Modal Bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

Change the place of your `loadingoverlay`. the `loadingoverlay` has to be in the modal.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb2uj3cs/)

Need to also give the setInterval for javascript spinner.

Comment: If the `loadingoverlay` is in the modal, it won't have unified style with the other pages.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give a bigger `z-index` to the Loading Spinner, than the Modal's `z-index`.

Let's try this:

```
#loadingoverlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide the z-index value. Thats creating issue

z-index: 9999;